# read HDFS blocks in Rstudio

Tags: r, hadoop

I want to read `HDFS` file in Rstudio ,it's not a CSV file which is easy to do, but they are blocks. I loaded data from a database with sqoop , and so I have data divided in blocks. 
I have files like this:

```
/data/_SUCCESS
/data/part-m-00000
/data/part-m-00001
/data/part-m-00002
/data/part-m-00003
/data/part-m-00004
/data/part-m-00005
```

but I can't read all the files , with this command  I can read only one at a time :
`hdfs.data <- file.path(hdfs.root,"part-m-00001"` // change the part-m-0000* every time , the * doesn't work to read all the files ...

Answer (score 1):

Are they text files? You should be able to load the in the same way as csv files.

```
list_tables <- lapply(list.files(hdfs.root,full.names = TRUE), read.table)
library(data.table)
table_composite <- rbindlist(list_tables)
```

You should include the options of read.table as arguments of lapply

Alternatively, you can read the full folder as a composite csv file.

Another option is using the open-source package rhdfs.

Comment: not a txt file , as i mention , i see , part-m-00001 ... 
what do you mean by ull.name ? do i need to write down part-m-0001 part-m-0002. etc ?

Comment: Which is the file format? Can you open it with a text editor like vim? If so, you can read it using read.table.

Comment: no,it's not a txt format, i tried to open it with nano, an empty file ,but to visualise the data : i type : hadoop fs -ls /data
and i can see all data on the terminal .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

It loads HDFS data to local where R install. And you can do rest of the stuff on data!

```
library(data.table)
sdf_local <- fread(paste("hadoop", "fs -text <HDFS file path>"))
head(sdf_local)


Note :<HDFS file path> should be complete path to the file
```